# No internet. No tethering. Solving this once and for all

Tags: wireless, internet, fedora, tethering

I have been using Ubuntu for more than a year, now. I had some problems after updating for Ubuntu 16, which I was able to solve.
My internet connection started being shaky some months ago. It would go down for a few seconds from time to time. Suddenly (maybe after an update, I do not really know) it just stopped working completely. Tethering is not working either.

I could start saying all I can say about my computer and my problem, but I do not really know where to aim at, so I would like you to help me with that: what commands should I run in order to obtain the relevant information to post here?

It is worth saying that I am not an experienced user, so please be detailed.

I am using my windows partition to access the internet.

---

Results of the wireless-info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24907443/

---

Again, after removing the broadcom module: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24908671/

---

**Update:**

After half an year with this problem, I decided to erase my Ubuntu installation and install Fedora26. But first, I gave Fedora a try directly from the installation pen. *Still no wi-fi nor tethering*. It says that the airplane mode is on, and that I should press the hardware switch. But pressing it does nothing (its color remains orange (off)). So, it seems that my computer has a problem with linux, because when using Windows10 I have no problems. It is strange, though, because I used Ubuntu for almost an entire year without such problems with Wi-fi. I have no idea how to procced, and it is strange and sad that so many other people have this problem, and yet I found no solution.

Comment: run the [wireless info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and add the output to your question, or if it is too long (the editor will tell you) post it on http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the link

Comment: @Zanna  It is done

Comment: Thanks :) Your wireless is apparently hard blocked, meaning you need to use the hardware switch to enable wifi. It could be a keyboard key or Fn key combination, another kind of physical button, or a firmware setting. Or, airplane mode may be on. Please check these things. See also [Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](//askubuntu.com/q/455030) for your other issues. Please update your question and let us know if you fix it. I'm not at all a wireless expert, but other folks here are :)

Comment: @Zanna My hardware switch does nothing: it is orange (meaning off) and, when I click it, it does not turn white (on). When I had internet, it was also orange, though. It seems like the hardware switch is not affecting anything... If I do "rfkill unblock all" it also does not work - it remains blocked.
I want to try and follow the answer in the link you sent me, but I do not have cable connection right now :)

Comment: `rfkill` can't unblock hard blocks... but I myself don't know what to suggest in relation to that.

Comment: Remove the broadcom module and reboot `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and post new script result `./wireless-info`

Comment: @Jeremy31 sorry: did not understand: the code you wrote removes the "broadcom module"? So I just run this code, reboot, and rerun wireless-info?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @Jeremy31 Ok, I've done it.

Comment: See if `echo "blacklist hp-wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/hp-wmi.conf` and a reboot helps

Comment: @Jeremy31 It did not help. The light of the hardware switch is now white, but I still don't have wifi. And sometimes it would turn white randomly anyway, so I am not sure that this is a consequence of what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Just found issue with Samsung Galaxy S7 Android and Ubuntu USB tethering..  When usb tethering, the mac address assigned is all zeros's... The mac needs to be changed to something other than all zero's.. I installed macchanger and macchanger-gtk.  Then from command prompt run sudo macchanger gtk, you can select the usb tethering interface and change mac, the connection should come right up after that..

Comment: additional detail instructions for macchanger:  https://websiteforstudents.com/change-ubuntu-systems-mac-addresses/